# how should i store user name using NS Userdefault in swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

```
import SwiftUI

private var  Username = ""

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      
    if  (UserDefaults.standard.set(self.username, forKey: "Username") != nil) {
            login()
        }else
        {
            home()
        } 
    }
}
```

I am not able to get a proper answer how to store username of a log in screen in user default  using swift UI.
i had try giving condition to go to login screen via content viewer   but i am not getting the idea to code it.
can any body tell me the steps i should follow
or post a sample program code so that i can refer ???????

Comment: Look up `@AppStorage` the code you have will not automatically update because nothing is observing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @AppStorage to store and get values for user defaults.

```
@AppStorage("Username") var username: String = ""
```

or you can use also use UserDefaults.

```
if !UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Username") {
     login()
} else {
    home()
}
```

Comment: if ((UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Username") == nil)) {
             login()
        } else {
            home()
        }

i had to modify like this in order to get the correct  output and eliminate all the errors

now it work 
thanks man

Answer (score -1):

Try checking out this article on how to use text fields in order to store typing details in swiftUI.

https://blckbirds.com/post/login-page-in-swiftui-1/

This guy has given you a breakdown of everything step by step just try to check him out. Explanation about text fields starts in the middle of the website

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed in SO. Overtime links break. If there is any relevant code in the link please share that code.

Comment: but here is only showing us to build the log in screen there is no lines telling us about userdefault and he is not even navigating from 1 page to another

Comment: @loremipsum oh okay Thank you for letting me know that. I will avoid using links.